# Styling text retrieved using file_get_content

Tags: php, html, css, parsing

I have long text being extracted using `file_get_contents()`. The text file contains information in the following format:

```
---
Description:
---
Some description here, with long text sentences.

---
Part 1
---
Information with part 1 in this section followed by path 2.
```

Now i wish to style the information between `---`, for example i would like to make "description" and "Part 1" bold and display the rest in plain text.

I think that can be achieved by preg_match. But i would like to know if any other method can be used too.

Comment: Can the text between `---` pairs ever contain hyphens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
preg_replace('/---(.*?)---/s', '<strong>$1</strong>', $text);
```

The expression captures anything between `----` pairs. `$1` in the replacement pattern indicates a backreference - it contains what was matched by the first capturing group. The `s` modifier makes `.` also match the newlines.

---

If you'd like to also remove the whitespace, you could do this:

```
preg_replace('/---\s*(.*?)\s*---/s', '<strong>$1</strong>', $text);
```

If there's a possibility that `---` pairs occur inside the text, then you can use the following pattern instead:

```
preg_replace('/---(?=\s)(\s)([^\r\n]+)(\s)---/s','<strong>$2</strong>$3', $text);
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tJ3hO0)

Comment: This should work for all reasonable possible examples, but if you did have three contiguous hyphens inside any of the "titles", it will break up that title.

Comment: @faintsignal: That's fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use also **explode**

```
$expl = explode("---",$yourtext);
echo '<b>'.$expl[0].'</b>'; //**Description:**
echo $expl[1]; //Some description here, with long text sentences.
echo '<b>'.$expl[2].'</b>'; //**Part 1**
echo $expl[3]; //Information with part 1 in this section followed by path 2.
```

Comment: The text can be fairly long and variable. Hardcoding might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to do this. The following will work even if you have hyphens in the text you want bolded.

```
echo preg_replace('/---(\r\n|\n|\r)([^\n\r]+)(\r\n|\n|\r)---/s', '<strong>$2</strong>$3', $text);
```

For example, suppose your text is:

```
---  
Descrip---tion:
---  
Some description here, with long text sentences.  

---  
Part 1  
---  
Information with part 1 in this section followed by path 2.
```

The above code would replace this with:

```
<strong>Descrip---tion:</strong>

Some description here, with long text sentences.

<strong>Part 1</strong>

Information with part 1 in this section followed by path 2.
```

Comment: Just a note: you don't need to escape `-` outside character class.

Comment: Right, it's a bad habit of mine. Took them out, thanks.